# How to get Local User Accounts listed in People Search?

Tags: search, people-search

I have created a development environment for my SharePoint 2010 installation. I have all the basic features I need working including site searches.

I have added an Enterprise Search page into my SharePoint site that allows me to search in both Sites and People. However, I can only seem to see my local Administrator account returned in the People search.

I decided to add a few more local accounts to see if SharePoint would pick them up. But it doesn't seem to be doing so. Even after a manual recrawl. I am quite new to SharePoint 2010 so I am probably going about this the wrong way.

In my development environment I really need to be able to add a few more people to allow me to develop a custom webpart I am working on.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add people to your Content source?

Sps3://yoursite

Also adding people to usersnlist can take time to propagate correctly.

Did you consider configuring user profiles for this? It can be tricky to set up, but that would give you all your AD users and the full sharepoint user profile to work with http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Comment: Ah thats what I missed. The cotent source. Thanks!

Comment: also remember to set "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers" permission for your default content access account (that you setup in search)